# Kubernetes LoadBalancer with both HTTPS and TCP traffic

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an HTTP LoadBalancer on Google Kubernetes Engine that is configured with nginx-ingress to serve website traffic.  I would now also like to expose a database (PostgreSQL) on port 5432.  How do I do that without the cost of a separate LoadBalancer?  nginx-ingress seems to only support HTTP traffic.

Comment: Have you tried with nginx-ingress and postgre 5432 services with type=NodePort and then use the gke web to create the load balancer manually as suggested in this [article](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1449)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Actually, never mind; see https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/c525f568e5b2c5fb234706c67c9a453d4248ee9f/examples/customization/nginx-config.yaml#L35 for how to add a main snippet via NGINX ingress configmap. Lookup how to use NGINX as a TCP proxy and put that snippet there

---

Configuration snippets available via annotations don't allow you to add a whole server. Meaning the standard ingress controller deployment can't do what you are asking. You'll have to put together a custom deployment yourself to add another server snippet.